# Scheduled alarms will lost when switched off the android phone

Tags: android

Is there any way to recover the lost alarms when switched on the phone? I have an application that allows the users to add reminders for corresponding dates.It works fine before switched off the phone.If the  phone is switched off it doesn't work,all the reminders will lost

Comment: See this [Tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#boot) and download the demo given there.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected Android behavior. The AlarmManager is designed this way. To get around this you can have a BroadcastReceiver which reschedules all your alarms (when it receives the ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETE intent which gets sent when the system boots up). To do this you need to register this permission with your AndroidManifest.xml and create an appropriate BroadcastReceiver

Android 5.0 also provides you with the option of the JobScheduler API which allows you to persist jobs through system reboots.

Comment: how can i reschedule all the alarms?

Comment: i created a broadcast reciever and reschedules all the alarms by retrieving the reminders from database,But the reminder notified the event after the boot completed despite of reminder's date

Comment: To solve this, you need if else logic to check if the user should be notified or not. If the date is in the past, then do nothing else add the reminder to be scheduled.

Comment: for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
   {
    Data d=not_al.get(i);
    int id=d.getId();
    String sid=String.valueOf(id);
     date=d.getEdate();
    int dat=getDate(date);
    eve=d.getEvent();
    mdate=d.getMdate();
    day=d.getDay();
    c.set(2015, dat, xactdate);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,2);
    PendingIntent p=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, in, 0);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(),p);
   
  }

Comment: This is my code,i think it contains so many problems,but i have no idea how to resolve it